# Using a subset of an object in different services

Tags: c#, .net, object, serialization, strong-typing

lets say that I have a system that heavily relies on a single object, for example a Person.
I have a storage service (service 1) that handles basic CRUD operations for Person, and saves this person in mongo.
But this Person object is very big and nested, it has a lot of properties, some of them are irrelevant for some of the other services.
For example we have service 2 that gets a Person object from the storage service and renders it in the ui, he only cares about some of the properties and doesnt need the whole big and nested Person object.
And we have service 3 that gets a Person object from the storage service and needs a diff subset of properties then service 2.

We are using .Net so everything is strongly typed.
The straightforward solution is to define a subset of the Person class in each of the services, and have some converter that converts the Person object to the object this service needs (removing irrelevant properties). But some services need the exact Person object besides 5-10 properties, and as I said the Person is a huge nested object.

What is the best practice for this scenario? We dont want to re define a new “”mini person” for every service with its relevant properties because that feels like huge code duplication + creating heavy dependencies between every service and the storage service.
But we are using .Net so we have to have some strongly typed object, otherwise we wont be able to make any manipulations on the object we received from the storage service, considering we dont want to use it as plain json and just traverse the keys.

We thought of 2 solutions:
First is to use the same Person object between all services. Each service will get the person obj, so any manipulation it needs and then serialize it with a custom serializer that removes some keys from the json, this way the one whos getting the response will get only the relevant props.
Second is to add some kind of annotations to the props that says “if the req came from service 2 then do json ignore” and just dont serialize this prop in the return value from the storage service. But this makes the storage service notnot isolated and simple, and this way in service 2 we again cant deserialize and manipulate the obj cause we dont have a strongly typed “mini person”, so we have to use the json.

Is there a better known solution for this situation?
And again, this is under the assumption that the Person obj is huge and requires a lot of work do re define it again and again and will create heavy dependencies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking best practices, maybe this Person object shouldn't have gotten so big to begin with. You can always break nested arrays and objects in their own separate files, entities or mongo collection.

But as it stands, maybe you could use dynamic or IDictionary<string, object> instead of creating a type Person and mapping every single strongly typed field in that class.

```
using System.Dynamic;

var person_from_database = person_repository.GetById(1);

dynamic person_result = new ExpandoObject();

person_result.name = person_from_database.fullname; //declare whatever properties your services need
person_result.first_address = person_from_database.addresses[0]; //even nested arrays and objects

person_result.name = person_result.name.ToUpper(); //modify values if needed

return Ok(person_result); //return whatever, no mapping
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0)!